# Complexity Of Nested Loop, With Outer Loop Variable Diminishing By Half Each Iteration

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
void G(....) 
{
  for ( int k = n/2; k > 0; k /= 2 ) 
  { 
    for ( int m = 0; m < n; m++) 
      a[(k+m)%n]=k+m;
  }                      
}
```

I'm unsure how to count the loop operations when the loop initiator and increment is like `(n/2)` and `(k/=2)` respectively..and so on. Running this code on a compiler for different values of n gave me interesting results, such as if n is 2^x then the iterations are n * x for values of n until 2^(x+1) -1. Now I'm stuck and don't know which Big Oh function to classify this as. Any answers/feedback/suggested learning methods/explanations welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop runs for 
*k* = n / 2, n / 4, n / 8, ..., *. 
It altogether runs *Θ(log(n))* times - that is the order needed to reduce *n / 2* to 1 by successive division by 2.

For each value of *k*, irrespective of the value, the inner loop runs *n* times, and so the inner loop + body run in *Θ(n)* time.

Since the inner loop + body take the same time irrespective of the value of the outer loop, we need to multiply the number of times the outer loop runs, by the running time of the inner loop + body. This is *Θ(n log(n))*.